# jQuery .height() not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to center a Modal Window on the screen (Which works completely fine), apart from when I'm adding content to it via jQuery and THEN getting it's width & height to center, it will always output the height as `0` instead of it's intended height. Here's my code:

```
        // Now to use the Data and add it to the Modal Window...
        $('#portfolioModal .inner .data').html('<h1>' + parsedData['name'] + '</h1>\n' + parsedData['desc'] + '');

        var modalWidth = $('#portfolioModal').width(); // Get the Modal Window's Width
        var modalHeight = $('#portfolioModal').height(); // Get the Modal Window's Height

        alert(modalHeight);

        var left = (windowWidth / 2) - (modalWidth / 2); // Calculate the left margin for center alignment
        var top = (windowHeight / 2) - (modalHeight / 2); // And calculate the top margin for center alignment

        $('#portfolioModal').css({ // Append the Left and Top margin to the Modal Window
            'left': left,
            'top': top
        });
```

Modal HTML:

```
        <div id="portfolioMask">
                    <div id="portfolioModal">
                                <div class="inner">
                                            <div id="portfolioModalClose">Close</div>
                                            <span class="data"></span>
                                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: which modal you using? HTML with fiddle would be helpful as well

Comment: Have you changed the `display:` css attribute from block to inline? That could cause your dialog to not have height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the div is hidden (`display:none`) when you fire the jQuery height() - it will always return a height of 0. I believe this is due to it not actually taking up space on your page - meaning its not really a part of it without being displayed. If you want to keep the div hidden, but want to get the height I recommend using the following CSS:

```
position:absolute;
visibility: hidden;
```

Using visibility hidden will make the element take up space in the dom but keep it from being visible - so it will have a height. Using position of absolute will pop it out of your actual page, so its not forcing content on your page to get pushed around by its height / width.

I personally also like to add a

```
left: -30000px;
```

I've found that some older IE's don't play well with this work around and floating the divs off the page ensures they're not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try $('#portfolioModal').css('height');

### Update:

```
// Now to use the Data and add it to the Modal Window...
$('#portfolioModal .inner .data').append('<h1>' + parsedData['name'] + '</h1>\n' + parsedData['desc'] + '', function(){
  var modalWidth = $('#portfolioModal').width(); // Get the Modal Window's Width
  var modalHeight = $('#portfolioModal').height(); // Get the Modal Window's Height

  alert(modalHeight);

  var left = (windowWidth / 2) - (modalWidth / 2); // Calculate the left margin for center alignment
  var top = (windowHeight / 2) - (modalHeight / 2); // And calculate the top margin for center alignment

  $('#portfolioModal').css({ // Append the Left and Top margin to the Modal Window
      'left': left,
      'top': top
  });

});
```

Comment: So you make the window, feed it data then want it's size, correct? If so, maybe you should put this in a callback after the data has been fed into the window?

Comment: How could I do that? Please explain it to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - I tested it with an `alert();` but nothing. EDIT: Tested your example code, doesn't work, no errors in Console, none of the code is executed. It's my understanding that `.html()` doesn't have a callback.

Comment: I'm silly. It's early, .html() doesn't have a callback. Try .append() instead, it does have a callback.

Comment: Still nothing. I couldn't find anywhere on the jQuery Docs that says `.append()` has a callback either, and it has the same effect as adding a callback to `.html()`, the code isn't executed and no error is given in the console.

Answer (score 0):

IS the dialog in a div? If it's a span, it will always return 0.

Comment: `portfolioModal` is a div, yes.

Comment: The only other jQuery code is parsing Data from an element creating the `parsedData` Array, but I'll post the HTML in my OP.

Comment: The element is just an element. `display: block;` on a span makes it exactly like a div. Don't get confused on default element styles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify pixel in left and top variable.

```
var left = (1024 / 2) - (modalWidth / 2) + "px"; 
var top = (768 / 2) - (modalHeight / 2) + "px"; 

$('#portfolioModal').css({ 
   'margin-left': left,
   'margin-top': top
 });
```